# Entity Framework Core 3 - No database provider error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

Working on my first MVC Core project and I'm trying to get the database context setup in the config services of Startup.cs but keep getting the error:

```
No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.
```

If I use the OnConfiguring override in the DbContext it works. This code will connect:

```
public partial class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext()
        {
        }

        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AbraEmployee> AbraEmployee { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                     .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))
                     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                     .Build();
                optionsBuilder.UseOracle(configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"));
            }
        }
}
```

However, if I comment that out and use the following in my Start.cs then I get the error.

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddTransient<IDataManager, DataManager>();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            //setting connstring separately here just to be able confirm correct value. 
            var connstring = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => {
                options.UseOracle(connstring);
            });

        }
```

I've looked at several different posts about the error but all basically say to make sure to have the constructor in DbContext accept DbContextOptions which my context seems to be setup correctly. The only other thing I found was to make sure to have IHttpContextAccessor in the ConfigServices.

Anyone have an idea on what I'm missing?

Comment: When I did a table scaffolding with EF it put all of the constructor code in the DataContext when it created it. If I comment it out it won't compile when I use "using (var ctx = new DataContext())" to connect up with the DataContext.

Comment: I've tried it myself on my side, the extra paramerless constructor is no harm. It just works normally on my side. Actually the error is thrown when you use `new DataContext()` ***BUT*** you commented all the code in `OnConfiguring`. Of course that's wrong. You should stick to using DI to obtain an instance of `DbContext` once you configure it in the `Startup.cs`

Comment: next time, do remember to post the code where the exception is thrown at as well. That would be easier for the others to help you. Sometimes I forget that simple thing because of focusing too much on the error message its own in case it looks just so simple (and fairly well-known), but actually in this case we did not see any code like `new DataContext()` posted in your question until you commented later above.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. The "using" statements were left over from our .Net Framework code. I got it all worked out to put it into DI and removed the "using" statements. This was a decent explanation that I found in case it helps anyone else. https://ardalis.com/avoid-wrapping-dbcontext-in-using/